# Raspberry Pi and Arduino bluetooth communication

Tags: python, bluetooth, arduino

I'm currently workin on a project which consists of controlling a arduino robot ( with this https://www.adafruit.com/products/1588 bluetooth module on it ) from my raspberry pi.

I found this tutorial http://blog.dawnrobotics.co.uk/2013/11/talking-to-a-bluetooth-serial-module-with-a-raspberry-pi/ and followed it without problems ( i just had troubles pairing my devices but now it seem to be OK  ;) ).

So i wrote a little piece of code ( i did not try the code in the tutorial ) to see if my robot was receiving order from my Pi but when i run this code, i get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
bluetoothSerial.write("forward")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 485, in write
raise SerialException('write failed: %s' % (v,))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not         connected
```

And here is the test code :

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import serial
import time

bluetoothSerial = serial.Serial( "/dev/rfcomm1", baudrate=9600 )
time.sleep(5)
bluetoothSerial.write( "forward") #Which normally make the robot go forward
```

Note that i'm able to connect to my arduino module using the command "sudo rfcomm connect hci0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" which return me that i'm connected :

```
Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to 96:76:B6:00:2B:AD on channel 1
Press CTRL-C for hangup
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution, it was ( according to this bug report https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1060457 ) my kernel who was not compatible with bluetooth rfcomm communication ( Kernel 3.12.6 and 3.12.8 )

So i just downgrade my Kernel to 3.10.6 and it works perfectly ;)